# Laravel application create event to update database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm developing an application in Laravel, my concept is ordered will be posted by buyers to buy particular items. I'm having a setting like order lifetime 5 min. This order will be notified to sellers whoever nearest to the buyer location. After 5 min completed need to take a list of viewed sellers and then need to change the order status as a timeout. I have to do this in my Laravel application hosted in VPS. Is there I can create events listen to the orders and update the status by using order date time and a current date time. Now I have a code like below and manually triggering this API, Is there any other way to do this automated. Please help any one

```
$postrequests = Buyrequest::where('request_closed' , 0)->whereDate('request_on', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
        if(count($postrequests) >0){
            $trade_execution = Adminsetting::where('id_admin_settings', 1)->selectRaw("TIME_TO_SEC(trade_execution_time) / 60 as trade_execution_time")->first();
        }
        foreach($postrequests as $request){
            if(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $request->request_on) < Carbon::now()->subMinutes($trade_execution->trade_execution_time)->toDateTimeString()){
                if($request->request_status == 0){
                    Buyrequest::where('id_buyrequest', $request->id_buyrequest)->update(['request_status' => 2, 'request_closed' => 1]);
                }else{
                    Buyrequest::where('id_buyrequest', $request->id_buyrequest)->update(['request_closed' => 1]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use task scheduling (i.e cron job)

Comment: Can I call cron jobs with request header? Because in my Lumen API I have created authentication for the request. And also can I run cron for every second? Will be getting any issue on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup [queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#running-the-queue-worker) to handle this situation. If buy request is created, then you can [dispatch job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#dispatching-jobs) and delay it to 5 mins, then worker will consume it after 5 mins.

```
dispatch((new BuyRequestJob($buyRequestId))->delay(now()->addMinutes(5));
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought like this only to delay the job queue and update the status in a DB table on job file. But what I feel whether any performance issue will happen? Because job post happen often and if I post job queue for 100 or 1000 or etc means whether will happen any issue?

Comment: 1k jobs are too less to cause problem since the job workload is low, unless it reaches 100k or sth then you need to consider to increase number of workers to consume jobs.

Comment: and the job only a few queries and should be completed immediately, delayed job only store on queue and do not have any workload usage = no performance issue.

Comment: Can I use eloquent ORM inside of queue class so that I can update  Buyrequest status inside that class? Is it possible?

Comment: yes, just like what you did in controller, can check laravel docs (generating job classes) https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#generating-job-classes